# Optimizing CSS for IE: Shadows via absolutely positioned divs

Tags: css, internet-explorer

My Thumbnails should have some shadows, I'd like to do this with some absolutely positioned `div`'s, because `tables` would create empty space in the bottom in IE. And the `div`'s also don't work in Internet Explorer.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
<div class="shadow text_box">
    <div class="slt"><font size="-1">&nbsp;</font></div>
      <div class="st"> <font size="-1">&nbsp;</font></div>
      <div class="srt"><font size="-1">&nbsp;</font></div>
    <div class="sl"><font size="-1">&nbsp;</font></div>
       <div class="sr"><font size="-1">&nbsp;</font></div>
    <div class="slb"><font size="-1">&nbsp;</font></div>
      <div class="sb"><font size="-1">&nbsp;</font></div>
      <div class="srb"><font size="-1">&nbsp;</font></div>

//Imagine, here's an image!

</div>
```

the css:

```
.text_box { background:#F7D76C; }

.shadow { position:relative;padding:0px;margin:8px; }

.slt { width:8px;height:8px;background:url(../img/shadow_left_top_xs.png) no-repeat bottom right; 
       position:absolute;top:-8px;left:-8px;height:8px;width:8px; }

.st { height:8px;background:url(../img/shadow_top_xs.png) repeat-x bottom left; 
      position:absolute;top:-8px;left:0px;height:8px;width:100%; }

.srt { width:8px;height:8px;background:url(../img/shadow_right_top_xs.png) no-repeat bottom left; 
       position:absolute;top:-8px;right:-8px;height:8px;width:8px; }

.sl { width:8px;background:url(../img/shadow_left_xs.png) repeat-y bottom right; 
      position:absolute;top:0px;left:-8px;height:100%;width:8px; }

.sr { width:8px;background:url(../img/shadow_right_xs.png) repeat-y bottom right; 
      position:absolute;top:0px;right:-8px;height:100%;width:8px; }

.slb { width:8px;height:8px;background:url(../img/shadow_left_bottom_xs.png) no-repeat bottom right; 
       position:absolute;bottom:-8px;left:-8px;height:8px;width:8px; }

.sb { height:8px;background:url(../img/shadow_bottom_xs.png) repeat-x bottom left; 
      position:absolute;bottom:-8px;left:0px;height:8px;width:100%; }

.srb { width:8px;height:8px;background:url(../img/shadow_right_bottom_xs.png) no-repeat bottom left; 
       position:absolute;bottom:-8px;right:-8px;height:8px;width:8px; }
```

Comment: Are you showing off your work, or do you have a question?

Comment: your style of writing html suits IE...

Comment: I would advise you to take a look at the code of Fancybox 1.3 (http://fancybox.net/) They also want to have cross-browser shadows and they succeed. Code is simpler than yours imo.

Comment: 1. show what you want to achieve. 2. ask an actual question 2. get a qualified answer

Comment: <font> is deprecated since html 4.01

Comment: Aside from being deprecated, there is no need for `font` tags because you have CSS classes assigned to your `div`'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a shadow is an aesthetical feature that has absolutely no real consequence other than to look slightly prettier.

Therefore, it is perfectly reasonable and acceptable to make the feature available only to supporting browsers, disregarding the old ones.

Consequently, just use `box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 4px black` and behold the awesome look of the shadow.

Seriously, nobody's going to miss a shadow around an image if they don't update their browser.